# Angular ng-options preselect a value using an option datasource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-select

I have an object like so:

```
$scope.properties = {
    1: 'Option A',
    2: 'Option B',
    3: 'Option C'
};
```

And an `ng-model` variable like so:

```
$scope.selectedValue = 2;
```

And some markup like so:

```
<select ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in ctl.properties" 
        ng-model="ctl.selectedValue">
</select>
```

But there seems to be absolutely no way of pre-selecting a value from that dropdown by its value. I've managed to get it to work if I set the selected value like this:

```
$scope.selectedValue = 'Option B';
```

How on earth do I get the `<select>` to pre-select using the option value (the key of the object) not the actual option text.

Please note, I'm not using an array of objects like mostly every article I've found uses. I've just got an object. I also don't want to change it to an array of objects. There must be a way to do this.

Many Thanks.

Comment: What version of angular do you use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dropdown needs a string key instead of a numeric one:

```
$scope.selectedValue = '2';
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/glouhaichi/pen/wrRNJq) as an example.

Comment: Thank you so much , I was so fixated on getting it working with the value, that I didn't think to retrieve the text using the value.

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help.

Comment: Okay so there's a slight problem with this, in that if the selectedValue is the string, when you then change the dropdown, the ng-model will overwrite the string with the actual value. So "Option C" if chosen sets the ng-model to "3" and that in turn would change the text of the option to "3"

Comment: I suspect something weird is happening in your controller, what version of AngularJS are you using ? Also take a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/glouhaichi/pen/wrRNJq) where you only need to select the key of the object for `ng-model` to work.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So I went back to using just the raw value, and it didn't work immediately, then I realised that `selectedValue = 2;` is different to `selectedValue = '2';`. Turns out that was causing an issue too!

Comment: Yes, it is, I will change my answer to reflect the right answer now.